# Outlook ItemAdd event not triggered consistently

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to decide whether the incoming mail is spam or not. Itemadd event works only once. It does not trigger consistently.

How can I fix this problem?

I do following:

```cs
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        inbox.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(InboxFolderItemAdded);
    }

    private void InboxFolderItemAdded(object Item)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I'm in!");
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            int[] answer = Predict(mail);

            if(answer[0] == 0) // Not spam
            {
                Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ((Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox));
                mail.Move(inboxFolder);
            }

            else if(answer[0] == 1) // Spam
            {
                Outlook.MAPIFolder junkFolder = ((Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk));
                mail.Move(junkFolder);
            }
        }
    }

    private int[] Predict(Outlook.MailItem mailBody)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm inside in predict function");
        double[]feature = featureExtraction.findFeatureIncomingMail(mailBody.Body);
        int[] answer = tree.Decide(feature);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

When i send myself mail, "I'm in" and "I'm inside in predict function" shows only once in debug console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your code won't compile  - there is no `ItemAdd` event on the `MAPIFolder` object. It is exposed by the `Items` object (returned from the `MAPIFolder.Items` property).

Secondly, the object raising the events (`Items`) must remain alive - declare it on the class level, not as a local variable, which gets released by the Garbage Collector when the `ThisAddIn_Startup` method exits.

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Working code will be like

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
 {
    Outlook.Items items=null;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = 
    Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    items=inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd += new 
    Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(InboxFolderItemAdded);
}

private void InboxFolderItemAdded(object Item)
{
    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in!");
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        int[] answer = Predict(mail);

        if(answer[0] == 0) // Not spam
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ((Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox));
            mail.Move(inboxFolder);
        }

        else if(answer[0] == 1) // Spam
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder junkFolder = ((Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk));
            mail.Move(junkFolder);
        }
    }
}

private int[] Predict(Outlook.MailItem mailBody)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("I'm inside in predict function");
    double[]feature = featureExtraction.findFeatureIncomingMail(mailBody.Body);
    int[] answer = tree.Decide(feature);
    return answer;
 }
}
```