# Why not all the new emails from Outlook go into c#?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-on

I'm trying to get emails from Outlook to c#.
In other words, every new email that arrives in the mailbox will reach me as well.
So I used:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
But there is a problem - not always a new email comes in, it comes to me, it could be that in the same run some new emails will come in and some will not.
I tried to check if there is a common denominator among the mails that are not perceived in the event and I did not find ...
please help me!
Here is the code ----

```
        public static void StartConection()
        {
            Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items Items = myInbox.Items;

            //when a new mail is comming go to ->RecivedMail
            Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(RecivedMail);
        }

        public static void RecivedMail(object Item)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

Comment: It might go to a different folder, based on outlook rules for incoming mails. Try to check different folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook ItemAdd event not triggered consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796672/outlook-itemadd-event-not-triggered-consistently). Check the second paragraph of the accepted answer.

Comment: yes!! thank you! I took the variable out as it was listed there and it still was not good ... but when I changed the class without static it worked !!